# How do I schedule a reboot on Linux?

Tags: linux, scheduled-task

I'd like to be able to schedule a server reboot at a specific time, but not regularly. How can I do this without futzing with adding and removing cron entries?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

If it is one-time deal, you can use shutdown command with `-r` as argument. Instead of using shutdown now, you can add time as parameter. Example:

```
shutdown -r 12:30
```

This also works with times in the early morning - so if it's 15:55 now, you can reboot the server at 3:15am tomorrow morning. You can also add `&` to put the command in background so you can log-off without killing the shutdown command. Example:

```
shutdown -r 03:15 &
```

In case, to cancel that reboot: run this:

```
shutdown -c
```

Comment: -r is critical otherwise you will be hitting a power button somewhere to bring it back up.

Comment: This also works with times in the early morning - so if it's 15:55 now, you can use 'shutdown -r 03:15 &' to reboot the server at 3:15am tomorrow morning.  (the '&' shunts the command the background so you can log-off without killing the shutdown command)

Comment: This has the advantage/drawback (depending on your use case) of alerting everyone every hour or so via a broadcast message of the upcoming reboot.

Comment: To cancel this schedule just `shutdown -c` without any other argument

Answer (score 20):

According to the man page: /sbin/shutdown [-t sec] [-arkhncfFHP] time [warning-message] found at -->
http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?shutdown+8

Load of options to choose from but, to answer your question.

To reboot in 5 minutes:
/sbin/shutdown -r 5 "reboot in five minutes"

To reboot at exactly 11:00 P.M.:
/sbin/shutdown -r 23:00 "rebooting at 11:00 P.M."

NOTE: your message will be broadcast to all active terminals / sessions.

Answer (score 8):

the `at` command is what you want.

```
at 5:00pm 
do
cd /
/full/path/to/init 6
done
```

`at -l` will list the at cmds

Comment: I would use `shutdown` instead of `init`. It's not necessary to do the `cd` or the `do`/`done` (which would probably produce an error).

Comment: really? I've used this for over 8 years and I've never has an issue.
hpux. solaris, linux 2.2 - 2.6

Comment: I personally prefer `init 6` myself; had intermittent issues with `shutdown -r` on some platforms in the past

Comment: I don't think that we should suggest to execute `init 6` on an unknown path, just because a user of Solaris suggests that. I think Solaris is nice but the OP was asking about the Linux kernel.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way I can think of is:

```
# sleep 2h && reboot
```

Run this as root.

Comment: what's about root permissinos?

Comment: as I said, run it as root.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "reboot" | at -m 23:00
```

....